# Descriptografia AES

Tags: criptografia, aes

Recebi hoje um arquivo `.txt`, dentro dele uma das colunas está criptografada. Já realizei a importação do mesmo no `SQL Server 2012`.

O cliente me passou a `chave` e me disse que foi criptografado `AES 128 ECB`

> Como faço para descriptografar essa coluna?

Comment: Você provavelmente vai descriptografar fora do banco de dados, ou seja, na sua camada de aplicação. A coluna do banco vai continuar criptografada e você pode, na sua aplicação, usar a chave que ele passou para ler os dados assim que eles chegarem do banco.

Comment: Entendi, mas não uso camada de aplicação, apenas vou realizar o select direto no banco mesmo, sem aplicação nenhuma.